# Linq grouping items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of myobject(let the list name be Mylist)

Each `myobject` has properties

```
SiteName ,
PersonName ,
numberOfClicks
```

From the *Mylist* I have to get a list of *SiteName* , *PersonName*, totalnumberOfClicks 
Ie one *siteName* one *PersonName* and sum of  *numberOfClicks* of this perticlaur person in the site

How this is possible in linq

Comment: You mean you want a list with distinct `PersonName`s? Or distinct pairs of `SiteName+PersonName`? Or aggregate sums of `numberOfClicks` for each `PersonName`?

Comment: distinct pairs of SiteName+PersonName

Comment: Ok, then you got the answer by @lazyberezovsky [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13948342/69809).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = from x in Mylist
            group x by new { x.SiteName, x.PersonName } into g
            select new { 
               g.Key.SiteName,
               g.Key.PersonName,
               totalnumberOfClicks = g.Sum(i => i.numberOfClicks)
            };
```

Query will return IEnumerable of anonymous objects with properties SiteName, PersonName, 
totalnumberOfClicks.

*BTW* in C# we use PascalCase for properties naming, and camelCase for variables naming (i.e. TotalNumberOfClicks, NumberOfClicks, and myList).